# How to get all paragraphs with regex?

Tags: regex

I have the text like below -

```
<p>Some long text 1</p><p>Some long text 2</p><p>Some long text 3</p>
```

and I would like to extract paragraphs' texts with regex. 
But if I use regex `<p>(.*)<\/p>`, I get `Some long text 1</p><p>Some long text 2</p><p>Some long text 3`, when I would like to get 3 elements: `Some long text 1`, `Some long text 2` and `Some long text 3`. How should I correct my regex?

Comment: Use lazy matching: `.*?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it non-greedy and get the matched group from index 1. `*` is greedy that matches as most as possible.

```
<p>(.*?)<\/p>
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX0wY1/1)

Read more about [✽ Want to Be Lazy? Think Twice.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#lazy_warning)

Try with [**Possessive Quantifiers**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

```
<p>([^<]*+)<\/p>
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX0wY1/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=<p>).*?(?=<\/p>)
```

This works.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/13

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below reegx which uses lookbehind and lookahead to match all the characters which are present inbetween the `<p>`,`</p>` tags.

```
(?<=<p>)[^<>]*(?=<\/p>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/14)